# In C, is there a way to cast a void pointer to a defined size type?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I need a “generic" **scanf** function that valids the input while also printing a message for the instruction and for the error. Scan is function that takes a void pointer, which is the direction of the variable that will store the input value, the specifier for the type, and the messages. The code looks like this:

```
void scan(char specifier, void *dest, string instruction, string error) {
bool success = true;
do {
    if(!success) {
        while (getchar()!='\n');
        perror(error);
    }
    puts(instruction);
    switch (specifier)
    {
    case 'd':
        success = scanf(" %d", (int *)dest);
        break;
        
    case 's’:
        // In this particular program I need the strings to be 30 bytes with spaces.
        success = scanf(“ %29[^\n]s", (char *)dest);
        break;

    case 'h':
        success = scanf(" %hd", (short *)dest);
        break;

    case 'f':
        success = scanf(" %f", (float *)dest);
        break;
    }
} while (!success ); }
```

But is it possible to just cast the void pointer to a pointer of a given size type instead of the `switch`? Like this:

```
double myVar;
size_t varSize = sizeof(double); void * dest = &myVar;
// specifierForDest is a string
scanf(specifierForDest, (varSize *)dest);
```

so that `dest` becomes a pointer to a variable of size `varSize`.

Or any other known method better than writing a `case` for every type in C?

Comment: Is the cast needed at all? All you need to is get the format string for the input.

Comment: "But is it possible to just cast the void pointer to a pointer of a given size type instead of the switch?" - not without being safe and avoiding undefined-behaviour, I don't believe so, no. But a `switch` statement is _very_ fast, so what's the problem?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You are trying to create some generic scan function and have decided the way to do it is to pass pointers to `scanf` and to convert those pointers to “pointers to a type of a certain size.” But that is not a correct solution because `scanf` is specified to take pointers to certain types, matching the conversion specifications, not merely pointers to types of a certain size. The answer to your literal question is yes, we can easily convert a pointer to a pointer to an n-byte object, with `(char (*)[n]) pointer`. But that not a proper way to achieve the goal.

Comment: I suggest you drop `scanf()` and: (1) use `fgets()` to read user input and (2) use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Comment: What you can do is change your function declaration to `void scan(char specifier, string instruction, string error, ...)`, so the pointer to the object to receive the value is in the `...`. Include `<stdarg.h>`. Inside the function, do whatever you want with printing instructions and whatnot. Then invoke `scanf` with `va_list ap); va_start(ap, error); int result = vfscanf(stdin, specifierForDest, ap); va_end(ap);`. That forwards the variable arguments to `vfscanf`. (In `va_start`, the second argument, `error`, must be the last named argument, the one before the `...`.)

Comment: it is X-Y problem. \

Comment: Your cast problems will disappear if you don't compile the C program using the C++ compiler. No casts are needed in the C language when using void * pointer

Comment: Your `scan()` function has `string` parameters. So is this C or C++?

Comment: @NikosC. I guess that is CS50 C compiled using VisualStudio as C++ code

Comment: @0___________ But then there's `puts(instruction)` which wouldn't work with `std::string`. So I don't know.

Comment: @NikosC. it is C code using the wrong compiler.

Comment: No, @0___________, CS50 is compiled with a C compiler.  But it provides a library and header that assignments for that class can / should use, and one of the things the header defines is a typedef `string` aliasing `char *`.  It's one of the things not to like about CS50.

Comment: I’m not using any C++ compiler, the strings are typedefs, `typedef char string[30];`.

Comment: 1. Never hide pointers behind typedefs 2. It will work

Comment: @AlexRosales The `s` in `" %30[^\n]s"` is wrong.  Drop it.

Comment: `" %30[^\n]s"` is a mistake to use with `char string[30]`.  Should be `" %29[^\n]"`.

Comment: Rather than `char specifier, void *dest`, pass the destination pointer (not casted to `void *`) and let code determine type (`_Generic`) and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. With all your suggestions I came up with this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char string[30];
void scan(string specifier, string instruction, string error, ...) {
bool success = true;
va_list ap; va_start(ap, error);
do {
    if(!success) {
        int c;
        do
            c = getchar();
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
        puts(error);
    }
    puts(instruction);
    success = vscanf(specifier, ap);
} while (!success );
va_end(ap); }
```

Which works fine.

Comment: `bool success = vscanf(...);` leads to an infintie loop when `vscanf()` returns `EOF`.  Likewise with `while (getchar()!='\n');`.

Comment: None of `string specifier, string instruction, string error` needs to use `string`.  Better with `const char *`.

Comment: Hmmm, re-use of `ap` in `vscanf(specifier, ap);` may be a problem ....?

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not provide a way to dynamically convert pointers to the types of pointers that `scanf` requires. This means that, once your function has received a `void *` argument, the only way for it to convert to the types that `scanf` is specified to receive is to handle them as individual cases.

An alternative is not to receive the argument as `void *` but rather to receive it in a variable argument list and forward it to `vscanf`, which is designed for this sort of operation. To do this, you must move the destination parameter to the end of the parameter list. Below is example code. The variable argument list handling is in the last few lines.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef char *string;


void scan(char specifier, string instruction, string error,...)
{
    bool success = true;
    do
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            int c;
            do
                c = getchar();
            while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
            perror(error);
        }
        puts(instruction);
        char *specifierForDest;
        switch (specifier)
        {
            case 'd': specifierForDest = " %d";       break;
            case 's': specifierForDest = " %30[^\n]"; break;
            case 'h': specifierForDest = " %hd";      break;
            case 'f': specifierForDest = " %f";       break;
            default:
                ;   // Do something here; do not neglect error cases.
        }
        va_list ap;           // Create argument list pointer.
        va_start(ap, error);  // Initialize argument list handling.
        success = 1 == vscanf(specifierForDest, ap);
                              // Forward argument to vscanf.
        va_end(ap);           // Clean up argument list handling.
    } while (!success);
}
```

Comment: Suggest `" %29[^\n]";` for OP's `typedef char string[30];`.